# Error binding parameter 14 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, django, sqlite

Here's my code for saving a staff profile into the sqlite3. What could i be missing?

```
....................
    def save(self):
        super(StaffProfile, self).save()
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)


        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell much from your description, but I'll guess that either (1) you didn't post your form or (2) you didn't check whether the form is valid or not, where if it isn't saving won't work.

An example of code from [the official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-model-formset-in-a-view):

```py
def manage_authors(request):
    AuthorFormSet = modelformset_factory(Author, fields=('name', 'title'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = AuthorFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            # do something.
    else:
        formset = AuthorFormSet()
    return render(request, 'manage_authors.html', {'formset': formset})
```

However, I will encourage you to switch to **class-based views** because it's a lot more flexible and simple than function-based views since Django already has [prewritten code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/) to support it. Do remember to add `.as_view()` if you include such classes in your `urls.py` file.